# GMapsFX - MarkerOptions cannot be updated once utilised to instantiate a Marker?

Tags: java, google-maps

A Marker object is instantiated with a MarkerOptions object; once this the Marker is instantiated, the options cannot be accessed.  The options contain a visible setting that is unsettable once associated with a Marker which seems incorrect.

Would anyone be able to through any light on the usage of the Marker and MarkerOptions within GMapsFX?

Comment: I think marker takes a deep copy of the markeroptions, and therefore it might caused your confusion? I think the correct way to update a marker is to create another markeroptions and apply the new markeroptions to the marker

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me.  As far as I can work out, MarkerOptions can only be assigned to a Marker at instantiation; this entails that a Marker cannot be updated with new MarkerOptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The author of the library has made an update that has been tested, fixing the issue.